# Add or delete values in an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

How can I add or delete values in an array?

Once I have my set of `int A[3] = {1, 2, 3}`, is it possible to change it this way: `A[2] = {1, 4}`?

I'm asking this after having read in a C++ manual that you can do something similar using operators `new` and `delete` instead of using STL (`vector`, `set`, `map`).

Comment: What do you mean by "add or delete"? An array is fixed-size.

Comment: You can't. An array has a set number of elements. You can only assign different values to them.

Comment: Yes, the thing is that I'd like to make it dynamic!

Comment: You're looking for `std::vector<>`, not arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are always a fixed size. You can pretend otherwise in a couple of ways:

1. Create a new array with the desired size, copy the elements you want from the old array into the new array, and then destroy the old array. Pretend the new array the same array as the old array.

   ```
   int *i = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3};

   // 'add' an element
   int *tmp = new int[4];
   std::copy(i, i+3, tmp);
   tmp[3] = 42;
   delete [] i;
   i = tmp;
   ```

   `std::vector` does this for you internally, and in a smarter way.
2. Create an array as big as you'll ever want and pretend that some number of elements at the end don't exist; 'changing the size' of the array consists of pretending a different number of elements at the end don't exist.

   ```
   int i[100];
   size_t size = 0; // number of elements that 'exist'

   // 'add' an element
   i[size++] = 42;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Pointers, new and delete! Sounds like you are talking about dynamic memory allocation.

Here it is explained nicely with a few examples: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/